# Google Translate - tracking word translations

Tags: python, google-translate

I am interested in getting the translation of a **specified Arabic word** in an Arabic sentence. I want to send an Arabic sentence to Google and identify the word from the resulting English translation. The problem is that, obviously, the word order and number of words of the two sentences won't match. I have tried bracketing the word with <> "" # () but this seems to change the translation of the word.

Comment: Have two similar sentences and compare translation. 
For example if this is arabic: `meow bow grrr susu` . Now you get english translation of it say: `cat dog angry pissing`. and if you wanted translation of `meow` which was arabic, then just know before hand arabic translation of `what is <meow>?` Now you have translation of it in English.

Then compare both English sentence to see which is common word.

Comment: Cant see that working because the words around the word I am interested will change the context of the word and thus the translation. I think if I could discover some character that simple mark the word but dont change the meaning that would be the ideal solution. Unfortunately Ive tried ! , * # ; : 1 and they all change the transalation of the word...

Comment: For anyone else interested: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/google-translate-api/authorname$3A%22tariq$20ahmad%22/google-translate-api/MuOtKfqt2FM